# Inno Setup: Uninstall user dialog

Tags: dialog, inno-setup, uninstallation

I need a user dialog with yes/no option for the uninstall process ("also delete the
setting files in the userappdata folder?" )!

How is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom form (`CreateCustomForm()`) or use a simple message box (`MsgBox()`) in the `CurUninstallStepChanged(usUninstall)` event function.